# I can not get video from the camera EmguCV

Tags: c#, emgucv

does not work Emgu.CV.Capture ()

```
public Form1() {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    grabber = new Emgu.CV.Capture();            
                    grabber.QueryFrame();
                    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);                        
                }

    void FrameGrabber(object sender, EventArgs e){
                    currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame();
                    if (currentFrame != null){
                        currentFrameCopy = currentFrame.Copy();
                        imageBoxFrameGrabber.Image = currentFrame;
                    }
                }
```

can not get a picture .. tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

When you start up your camera capture you need to actually tell it what camera to use.

This line:

```
grabber = new Emgu.CV.Capture();
```

Requires you to [tell it which camera](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/ef1ecb1e-dbbb-affd-3acd-d05d194d9023.htm), I would suggest changing it to this:

```
grabber = new Emgu.CV.Capture(0);
```

In theory it should open the deafult camera but it is worth being specific. On top of that

Comment: Unfortunately, this also does not work. And grabber = new Emgu.CV.Capture(@"filename") is work